Java.io.tmpdir directory doesn't exist
When I run a program on intelij it shows this error I have redownloaded it many times but the result is still the same. I am new to programming so I don't know how to do it Is there any way to fix this error?
This error
Abnormal build process termination:
"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-23\\bin\\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/jna/amd64" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=5099883117943016963 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2024.2 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/Hưởng/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/Hưởng/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Hưởng/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=21.0.4 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Hưởng/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2/compile-server/untitled2_1d2a6d90/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder.fs.case.sensitive=false "-Djps.kotlin.home=C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4\\plugins\\Kotlin\\kotlinc" -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path="C:\\Users\\HNG\~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\kotlin-idea-15111308323172465624-is-running" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/util_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/platform-loader.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/trove.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jetbrains.kotlinx.metadata.jvm.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/protobuf.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps/java-compiler-charts-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 61150 c22780a1-1eb9-40bb-9092-a243232e1493 C:/Users/Hưởng/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2/compile-server
WARNING: java.io.tmpdir directory does not exist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1161)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:340)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newMethodAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:71)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newMethodAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:154)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.acquireMethodAccessor(Method.java:726)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:43)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char \<?\> at index 11: C:/Users/H�?ng/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2/log/build-log\\build-log-jul.properties
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:204)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:175)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:231)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:148)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.LogSetup.initLoggers(LogSetup.java:30)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.\<clinit\>(BuildMain.java:43)

I tried to fix it but don't know how.

Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char \<?\> at index 11: C:/Users/H�?ng/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2/log/build-log\\build-log-jul.properties have you checked this? Looks like an encoding problem with that path

It looks like an encoding problem, but it could be a bug in IDEA. It's passing -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Hưởng/AppData/Local/JetBrains... on the command line. It's probably using the wrong encoding for the command line, but is there any way to change the encoding at this place?

An alternative option may be to change your user name to one that does not use Vietnamese characters but rather Latin characters only. I don't know how to change the user name but I believe the results of my search will help.

dir /ad/x C:\Users in cmd.exe might help you - by enabling you to use the 'DOS' name for your home directory as the value of the variable

@g00se good idea, but the IDE obtains this directory name via the standard Windows environment variable %LOCALAPPDATA%.

@k314159 I see what you mean. That could be overridden by a user-supplied value of that variable though. Worth a try before trying to find a better solution. Just amazing that Unicode issues are still a problem for Windows
